# Gdb attach fail: debugging fastcgi C++ app with Netbeans

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, gdb, fastcgi

I have written a test fastcgi app. I want to debug it, using the Netbeans IDE. When I attempt to attach to the process, I get the error:

Gdb could not attach to the specified process.

I then tried the following:

**sudo -i /bin/sh "path/to/netbeans"**

Attaching to the process still failed (Got the message: **Gdb could not attach to the specified process**).

I then tried the suggestion made at this [link](http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/18/gdb-attach-fails-with-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/#comment-141535)

That also failed. I got the nessage: **The executable associated with the selected project does not match the selected process ID.**. after changing the run path so that the project executable now points to my cgi-bin directory, I now get the error: **Gdb could not attach to the specified process**.

I am now at a loss as to how to debug my app, using Netbeans. In case netbeans can't do this, is there another visual debugger that I can use?

I am running Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans does have the ability to use gdb to attach to a process. From the link you posted did you also follow the "update" from the comments describing how to fix the kernel ptrace_scope issue in Ubuntu?

Another thing to try is to see if you get the same error [attaching](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_22.html) gdb via commandline, or if you really want to use a gui [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/). That way you can isolate whether it is Netbeans, gdb, or a permission problemn in Ubuntu.

Comment: Errr, I was worried someone would suggest DDD. It looks like something from the seventees... Looks aside, I couldn't even figure out how to 'Open Program' - because its interface was so counter intuitive.... I can't attach a process until I 'Open a Program' - yet, all attempts to open a program are thwarted by the GUI - which insists on pointing at my home directory ... SMH

Comment: Try attaching to the process via gdb command line.  Netbeans and DDD are just frontends to gdb.  http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_22.html

Comment: I CAN attach using gdb directly (if I run gdb as root), but I would prefer the GUI - because it is much more productive for me

Comment: While I prefer Netbeans I have had luck with Eclipse CDT in the past. http://eclipse.org/cdt/

Comment: After thinking about it some more. It still smells like a permission problem if you have to be root to attach with gdb. Double check the comments on the link you posted, there was a secondary fix there as well.